# Swift If program

Tags: swift, if-statement, random

Still a beginner with just playing around with some basic functions in swift.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this code?

```
import UIKit

var guessInt: Int
var randomNum = arc4random_uniform(10)

if Int(randomNum) == guessInt {
  println ("correct")
}  else {
  println; "no, the number is not. guess again"
}
```

So far the only error I'm getting is that

```
guessInt
```

is being used before being initialized!
 I've tried to type everything again but still have the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give guessInt a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift you cannot read a value before it's set, which you're doing here:

```
if Int(randomNum) == guessInt
```

If you change your declaration from this:

```
var guessInt:Int
```

to this:

```
var guessInt = 6
```

then your code will work as expected (assuming you want the user's guess to be `6`).

Answer (score 0):

You've *declared* `guessInt` but now you need to *initialize*, or set it to some initial value.

For example:

```
let guessInt = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to declare guessInt as an "Optional", meaning that it can be nil, in fact it will be initialized to nil.  This will print "no, ...." until you assign guessInit to a non nil value in the range of values produced by arc4random_uniform(10), but it will compile and run cleanly.

```
var guessInt:Int?   // note the ? after Int this marks it as an Optional
var randomNum = arc4random_uniform(10)
if Int(randomNum) == guessInt {
  println ("correct")
}  else {
  println; "no, the number is not. guess again"
}
```